# predict upvotes a review would get in a certain time period after publishing--yelp review

Tags: regression, predictive-models, topic-models

I've encountered this question online. How to design an algorithm to predict how many upvotes a review would get in a certain time period after publishing. Let's say the review comes from Yelp. So the problem becomes the following:

> Give millions of reviews (text) and their associated upvotes in a
>   certain time period, how do you design a ML predictive model?

Definitely, a lot of prior information may affect the upvotes of a certain review would got. For example:

```
(1) Who wrote this review, elite or a regular user?
(2) The business of the review. A review for a hot restaurant may get more upvotes than for a car mechanic. Generally speaking, when you have a Yelp's review record, it contains a business id.
(3) ...
```

Let's pass these prior information and focus on the text features. Can anyone give me some suggestions. I'm thinking using LDA (topic model) to generate a topics dictionary but still did not come out a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) is unsupervised learning (comparable to clustering) and IMO not a suitable for the task you sketch.

Think of supervised learning (e.g., Support Vector Machine (SVM)) with training and test data.

Comment: I kind of do not understand how to generate features from the review text?

Comment: @FihopZz You will have to find your research question to generate features. When you don't have any hypotheses (you should have some!) you can try word frequencies as a starting point.